# When shuffling elements (order of images), how do I keep the respective shuffled img source?

Tags: javascript, html

Im able to shuffle the order of images on a page (using a function found on this site), however when I click on a shuffled image so it opens in a new tab, the opened image is actually the previous image before everything was shuffled. How do I "set" each "link" to the source img for all the shuffled images so when I click on them, they open up the right image?

```js
function fnShuffle(elems)
{
    //alert("Shuffle!!")

    allElems = (function(){
 var ret = [], l = elems.length;
 while (l--) { ret[ret.length] = elems[l]; }
 return ret;
    })();
 
    var shuffled = (function(){
        var l = allElems.length, ret = [];
        while (l--) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * allElems.length),
                randEl = allElems[random].cloneNode(true);
            allElems.splice(random, 1);
            ret[ret.length] = randEl;
        }
        return ret; 
    })(), l = elems.length;
 
    while (l--) {
        elems[l].parentNode.insertBefore(shuffled[l], elems[l].nextSibling);
        elems[l].parentNode.removeChild(elems[l]);
    }
}

function fnClose()
{
 window.close() ;
}
```

```css
body
{
 margin:-3px;
 padding:10px;
 text-align:left;
 background-color:#212121;
 border:18px solid Black; 
}


#btnShuffle 
{
 position:fixed;
 color:White;
 background-color:Red;
 border: 1px solid White; 
 right:17px;
 top:45px; 

 border-radius:2px;
 padding:5px;
 width:25px;
 height:25px;

 text-align:center;
 font-size:12px;
 z-index:92;
 transition-duration:0.05s;
 box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
}

#btnShuffle:focus
{
 outline:0;
}

#btnShuffle:hover 
{
 background-color:#7d025c;
 color:Yellow;
 border:1px solid Red; 
}

#btnShuffle:active 
{
 background-color:Black;
 color:Yellow;
 border: 2px solid White; 
 box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 transform:translateY(1px) translateX(-1px);
}

#btnClose /*X*/
{
 text-align: center;
 position:fixed;
 text-align:center;
 color:White;
 background-color:Red;
 border: 1px solid White; 
 right:17px;
 top:15px; 

 border-radius:2px;
 padding:5px;
 width:25px;
 height:25px;

 text-align:center;
 font-size:14px;
 z-index:92;
 transition-duration:0.05s;
 box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
}

#btnClose:focus
{
 outline:0;
}

#btnClose:hover 
{
 background-color:#7d025c;
 color:White;
 border:1px solid Red;
}

#btnClose:active 
{
 background-color:#7d025c;
 color:Red;
 border: 2px solid Red; 
 box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 transform:translateY(1px) translateX(-1px);
}

.image 
{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 
 margin:2px;
 padding:2px;

 filter:drop-shadow(-1px 1px 4px black);
 overflow:hidden;
 filter:grayscale(100%) contrast(140%) brightness(70%) drop-shadow(-1px 1px 4px black); 
}

.image img
{
 min-width:auto;
 max-width:auto;
 min-height:250px;
 max-height:250px;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;

 vertical-align:center;
 outline:1px solid white;
 outline-offset:-1px;
 
 transition:0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.image:after 
{
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
 vertical-align:left; 

 top:1; left:1;
 
    width:100%; height:100%;

    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
 z-index:91;
 opacity:0;
 
}

.image:hover
{
 border-radius:0px;
 outline:3px solid White;
 
 outline-offset:-1px;
 filter:grayscale(0%) contrast(100%) brightness(100%) drop-shadow(-2px 2px 2px black);
}

.image:hover img
{
 filter:none;
 border-radius:0px;

 max-width:auto;
 max-height:248px;
 width:auto;
 height:100%;
 
 transform:scale(1.45);
 
}

.image:hover:after
{
 opacity:0.98;
 transition-delay:0.1s;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=test.css> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script> 
<input type="button" onclick="fnShuffle(document.querySelectorAll('.image'))" value="Shuffle" accesskey="s" id="btnShuffle">   

<span> <a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b1/ee/39/b1ee39ec9fbad7534b4aebd3b9c28f70.jpg" target="_blank"> <div class="image"> <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b1/ee/39/b1ee39ec9fbad7534b4aebd3b9c28f70.jpg" alt="" /> </div  >
<span> <a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQMffPacLDGt2fDiWo44Bw--FUC-ALLhDB3XDkrE-hFlvEjHHsK&usqp=CAU" target="_blank"> <div class="image"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQMffPacLDGt2fDiWo44Bw--FUC-ALLhDB3XDkrE-hFlvEjHHsK&usqp=CAU" alt="" /> </div>
<span> <a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQfG1nj6JpTXY_pLcxXFcfoN4fOapElgpF8MZMrPfawUTjYuOGb&usqp=CAU" target="_blank"> <div class="image"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQfG1nj6JpTXY_pLcxXFcfoN4fOapElgpF8MZMrPfawUTjYuOGb&usqp=CAU" alt="" /> </div>
```

Comment: Can you share [an example with codepen or snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we see what's going on.

Comment: yes, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/mLa0wpoz/

Comment: a) put the `<a>`  tags inside the `<div>`s that you're shuffling or b) select the `<a>` tags as the elements to shuffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're cloning just the image element not the `a` element that nests the image, that's why the href value(hyperlink to the image) always stays the same, even though the image is swapped.

I changed it by querying all classes `image-container` that is set on all `a` tags that hold the image, that way the `a` elements are swapped.

```
<input type="button" onclick="fnShuffle(document.querySelectorAll('.image-container'))" value="Shuffle" accesskey="s"
  id="btnShuffle">

<span>
  <a style="text-decoration:none" class="image-container"
    href="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b1/ee/39/b1ee39ec9fbad7534b4aebd3b9c28f70.jpg" target="_blank">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b1/ee/39/b1ee39ec9fbad7534b4aebd3b9c28f70.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</span>
```

[Here's a working example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lishipu/k1o9s2nb/3/)(can't use stack snippet because it's sandboxed, preventing testing clicking links)